# Current Limiting in DC Circuit

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Suppose I have an 8s lithium iron phosphate battery connected to an 80 A 24 to 12 V step down converter with adjustable output voltage. The output side connects to a 4s lithium iron phosphate battery at an appropriate bulk charging voltage such as 13.6 V, with a clamp meter monitoring current.

Poof, out comes the magic smoke because the converter has no built in limiter and the large 4s battery can take more amps than the converter can handle.

In this entirely theoretical scenario, what could i add to the input or output sides of this circuit to limit the current to 80 A or less?

Comment: "the large 4s battery can take more amps than the converter can handle" How does this make sense? Step-down converters deliver as much current as there is load, which has nothing to do with battery capacity.

Comment: Josh didn't say anything about the capacity.  A discharged LiFePO4 or Lion battery will have a very low impedance when discharged and if you apply the full charge termination voltage, you could sink 100's of amps into the battery (briefly before the pack catastrophically fails).  Chargers apply a lower voltage during the CI phase of charging (bulk charge) to limit the current.

Comment: This is really theoretical, but could be tested by connecting a fully charged 8s lfp and a 20% full 4s one. Applying the full charge voltage, say 13.8v to the nearly empty 4s sitting at 12.3v would send 100’s of amps (now I’m curious if there is a limit, or if the cables connecting the batteries would melt first). I was thinking about how i could limit that current with some kind of variable resistor  or other device, and what that device would be. Something like whatever a mppt charge controller uses to limit current going to the battery.

Comment: Please stop what you are doing before you start a fire and someone gets hurt. You must have constant current limit when charging lithium batteries. What you need is a battery charger for 4s which can take 24 V input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step down converter has a feedback circuit that samples the output voltage and regulates the output.  Adding a current sense resistor to the output (usually on the low side) connected to a comparitor that turns on at the desired current limit.  The comparitor output drives the feedback input of the step down converter above the threshold voltage which turns the switch in the step down converter off, limiting the current.

The catch is that there are loop stability issues that can make this more difficult than the obvious solution above, and a variety of other edge cases you need to handle for battery charging if you want to charge safely and preserve the lifespan of your batteries.

What you probably need to do is to get a step down converter that already has current limiting on the output (which you absolutely need for charging anyway), or get a dedicated battery step-down dc to dc battery charger which will have current limiting built in.

Comment: Thanks Dean, is this similar to how it would be done in a battery charger or solar charger where the current is actively limited to a set number of amps? If I understand the feedback circuit you described, the charger is essentially regulating the voltage constantly up or down to maintain an exact resistance value that results in maintaining the set current limit until the battery voltage approaches the peak programmed charging voltage, at which point current drops down to zero over time. And therefore there is no simple device such as a resistor I could put between the converter and battery?

Comment: Basically, yes.  There is no simple device you can put between the converter and battery to accurately limit current over the charge cycle.